# Testing Angular directive with Object as parameter

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I want to test my directive which receives an object from viewmodel. The directive works as expected but I can not write a test. I think it has sth to do with the passed object. Other directive tests with simple values works fine.

```
<dire status="ctrl.myObject"></dire>
```

Test:

```
var compile, scope, directiveElem;

beforeEach(function () {
module('App');
inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  compile = $compile;
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.myMock = {
    prop0: true,
    prop1: true
  };

  directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
});

});

function getCompiledElement() {
    var testDirective = '<dire status="' + scope.myMock + '"></dire>';
    var compiledElement = compile(testDirective)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return compiledElement;
  }

it('should have template', function () {
    var spanElement = directiveElem.find('dire');
    expect(spanElement).toBeDefined();
  });
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
Directive: dire should have template FAILED
    Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]].
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%5D%5D&p2=9&p3=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&p4=Object%5D
```

I hope someone can support me. Thanks.

Comment: This is *not* the way to pass a value to the directive. Use `var testDirective = '<dire status="myMock"></dire>';`. The `scope.myMock` is already set and you are OK.

Comment: Ok that works!

Is the described way correct to pass simple values to a directive? scope.val=1; I would pass with '<dire val="' + scope.val + '"></dire>'.

Comment: Yes, of course, it is the same principle!

Answer (score 0):

`myMock` is already set on `scope` which is included during the compile, so you can quite simply:

```
scope.myMock = {
    prop0: true,
    prop1: true
};
...
var testDirective = '<dire status="myMock"></dire>';
var compiledElement = compile(testDirective)(scope); <-- scope
```